# displaying the dictionnary values of error_messages

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I've used ridicoulus amounts of time trying to find the answer to this one, but either it doesn't exist on google, or I'm an idiot (rhetorical question, no need to answer)

I've found how to declare field specific error messages for the two keys '`required`' and '`invalid`', but I'm too stupid to figure out what syntax to use in the template in order for these error messages to be displayed. (sorry if it's annoying, I'm really in a self deprecating mood at the moment FML just doesn't cut it)

So, here is what hours of googling has gotten me so far. From forms.py

```
RegfirstnameError={'required': 'Last name must be filled in', 'invalid': 'invalid value in the last name field'}

class FrontpageRegistrartion(forms.Form):
    firstname = forms.CharField(label="", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':'firstnamespan', 'placeholder':'Fornavn',}), error_messages=RegfirstnameError,)
....
```

I've used the following syntax (I don't even know if I'm using that word correctly, I'm just hoping in the lack of anything else (I could google it, but honestly, the amounts I would have too google. It is amazing I've even gotten this far with my django adventure) in my template;

```
{% if regform.errors %}
    <h2 style="color: red;">En feil oppstod</h2>
{% for error in regform.errors %}
<p style="color: red;">
{{error}}
</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Which only renders the name of the field with an error. (I've of course tried different varieties, but none that work)

In case my non sensical explanatory super powers (over which, I have no control) has kicked in again, let me be super clair; I'm of course hoping to display the value of which ever of the two keys; '`required`' or '`invalid`' is appropriate for the circumstance / situation.

So, I'd be really appreciate of any feedback, including feedback that confirms my feelings of being a complete idiot! Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you are looking at the fields that have errors.

If you want to access the errors for a specific field, you need to loop over each field and then loop over each error in each field.

```
{% for field in regform %}
    {{ field }}

    {% for error in field.errors %}
        <small id="error_{{ forloop.counter }}_{{ field.auto_id }}">{{ error|safe }}</small>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

What you are accessing is useful to set classes based on whether there were any errors at all in the form (for things like bootstrap or displaying a message like you do)